# Selecting a NSCell with 1 click, without selecting the row first?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I select a NSTextFieldCell in a NSTableView, the behavior is different depending on the row is selected or not.

- If the row is selected the cell is immediately selected, and the cursor is blinking inside the text field
- If the row is not selected, the only change after the click is the selection of the row, but the cell doesn't go into edit mode.

I would like to have the cell into edit mode in both cases after 1 click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this method below, it will edit your cell:-

```
- (void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex row:(NSInteger)rowIndex withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to edit your cell with one click. For this you need to subclass your tableview and capture its mousedown: event as

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
  {

       NSPoint globalLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
       NSPoint localLocation = [self convertPoint:globalLocation fromView:nil];
       NSInteger clickedRow = [self rowAtPoint:localLocation];
       NSInteger clickedCol = [self columnAtPoint:localLocation];

       [super mouseDown:theEvent];

       [self editColumn:clickedCol row:clickedRow withEvent:theEvent select:YES];

  }
```